# How to use MultiSum function in Modelica?

Tags: function, sum, modelica

I've got a vector with a size of 5 and would like to sum each of its elements at each step in a variable (summ), but I don't know how to use MultiSum function in this case.

```
model add
import Modelica.Blocks.Math.MultiSum;
Real k[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
Real summ;
equation
for i in 1:4 loop
summ = MultiSum(???)
end for;

end add;
```

I would appreciate if you could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution by MarkusA is good, but if you **really** wanted to use the block you could do something like this:

```
model add
  import Modelica.Blocks.Math.MultiSum;
  Real k[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RealExpression realExpression[size(k, 1)](y=k);
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput summ;
  MultiSum multiSum(nu=size(k, 1));
equation
  connect(multiSum.y, summ);
  connect(realExpression.y, multiSum.u);
end add;
```

or with annotations:

```
model add
  import Modelica.Blocks.Math.MultiSum;
  Real k[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RealExpression realExpression[size(k, 1)](y=k)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-110,16},{-90,36}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput summ
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{86,4},{106,24}})));
  MultiSum multiSum(nu=size(k, 1))
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-10,20},{2,32}})));
equation 
  connect(multiSum.y, summ) annotation (Line(points={{3.02,26},{80,26},{80,14},{
          96,14}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(realExpression.y, multiSum.u)
    annotation (Line(points={{-89,26},{-10,26}}, color={0,0,127}));
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end add;
```

Comment: Dear Hans, your solution works pretty well. Using this solution, I tried to edit the code in order to use "while loop", but was not successful. To be more specific, I actually intend to sum the elements of this vector up to element 3 (k[3]). Is it possible to use "while clause" when we have "connect" in equation section?

Comment: No, connect cannot be in a while-loop. And since while can only occur in algorithms it also prevents some optimizations, I would personally use the solution by MarkusA

Comment: I extended my answer to have a parameter up to which the sum of the vector is computed.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to call a block as a function. This is currently not allowed in Modelica. There is a [proposal](https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/issues/1512) (as [PDF](https://svn.modelica.org/projects/MCP/public/MCP-0012_CallingBlocksAsFunctions/MCP-0012_CallingBlocksAsFunctions.pdf)) to enable this, but it is still in discussion.
Therefore you need to call a `function`. Many of them are defined in `Modelica.Math` or a built-in (depending on the tool you use).

If you really want to use the block in the model it is necessary to create an instance of the block. As an alternative, it makes sense to re-use the code from the block.

Still there is a simpler way to do what you want, using the built-in function `sum`, which is defined in the [Modelica Language Specification](https://modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf), Section 10.3.4 "Reduction Functions and Operators".

```
model add
  Real k[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
  Real summ;
equation 
  summ = sum(k);
end add;
```

Note: In Section 10.3.4 "Reduction Functions and Operators" you will find how it is possible to add a `for` statement to the `sum` function to customize it. Using this to compute the sum of `n` elements would be:

```
model addN
  parameter Integer n(max=size(k,1)) = 3;
  Real k[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
  Real summ;
equation 
  summ = sum(k[i] for i in 1:n);
end addN;
```